# 0.0% test Coverage - Sonar maven-surefire-plugin JUnit test-suite integration

Tags: unit-testing, maven, junit, code-coverage, sonarqube

We are running Sonar 3.5, using test-suites, and executing them using maven-surefire-plugin. While our tests compile and execute correctly using maven, when we run sonar against them, we are still getting 0.0% Test Coverage in SONAR. Any idea what we're doing wrong?

Maven-surefire-plugin configuration in pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>    
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>    
    <configuration>    
        <test>com.myApp.AllTests</test>    
        <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This test-suite looks like this:

```
package com.myApp;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

/**
 * 
 * @author me <a href="mailto:my@myapp.com">Me</a>
 *
 */
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ TestA.class })
public class AllTests {

}
```

Comment: You should use emma, jacoco or other coverage tool

Comment: I was thinking about that. In my implementation, if I do not use test-suites, I am able to get test coverage metrics. So, I think the issue is the use of test-suites with Sonar, not which coverage tool I'm using.